# Discrete time series Forecasting : predict the time & the quantity of certain thing?

Tags: time, series, forecasting

Here is the deal:

I have the inventory data:both ***the time*** and ***quantity*** of certain product shipping into the stock. Based on this data, how to predict **the time** and **quantity** of future shipping into this stock?

I wanna get both the time and quantity information.

Comment: Are you assuming a constant demand?  Seasonal demand?  You have to decide which forecasting model you want to use.

Comment: I wanna predict the certain time & associated quantity of that product would be shipped into the stock. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave you two.  Constant demand and seasonal demand.  Constant demand assumes that people will buy the product constantly, like toilet paper.  Oops, those predictions went way wrong recently.  Seasonal demand assumes that people stock up on certain products at certain times of the year, like Christmas shopping.  Now, you have to pick a model.

Comment: I think I need both of those two models. Because there are several kinds of products shipped to the stock, they are of different trend. Remeber what I am looking for? Based on the current data, predict the time and quantity of that product shipped into the stock.

Comment: Constant demand is easy.  Figure out how much product you're moving a month, and order that much each month.  Seasonal demand requires a year or two of ordering information.  You order more when the demand is high and less when the demand is low, based on month to month ordering information.

Comment: OK, I wanna know for those time-series forecasting models, whether the time of certain thing happening in the future could also be identified?